# How to reorder a sequence of 4 numbers in a string using bash script on unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXTENT=`ogrinfo -so area.geojson ogrgeojson | grep Extent | sed 's/Extent: //g' | sed 's/(//g' | sed 's/)//g' | sed 's/ - /, /g'`
echo $EXTENT
EXTENT=`echo $EXTENT | awk -F ',' '{print $1 " " $4 " " $3 " " $2}'`
echo $EXTENT
```

and for some reason it eats up some of the numbers and output:

```
12.834778, 52.014472, 13.610687, 52.399905
13.610687 52.014472
```

where expected on the second line is the 4 numbers.

The thing that I do not understand is that, if i copy paste the 4 commands myself to terminal everything works as expected. What do i need to do to make it work in a bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to reproduce your problem was this:

```
$ echo $'12.834778\r, 52.014472\r, 13.610687\r, 52.399905'    |
   awk -F ',' '{print $1 " " $4 " " $3 " " $2}'
52.014472  13.610687
```

Please remove the "carriage returns" in your file and you should be fine.